# Current in circuit with switch

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor

[image: Circuit]

Switch is open in this circuit. How do I know that current IL (inductor) is 0 and voltage(Uc) of capacitor is 0 when the switch is open(t<0)? Can someone explain me this as simple as possible.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar if you want to make a more legible diagram. It looks like a homework question so you need to show your attempt at a solution. We wouldn't like you getting qualified if you don't understand the theory. :^)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a homework question with no attempt as solving it.

Answer (score 1):

When the switch is open there is nothing to add energy to the circuit. Ideal capacitors and inductors don't consume energy gut resistors do, so if you wait long enough, the resistor will use up all the energy in the circuit. With these sorts of questions, unless it states explicitly that the capacitor is charged or there's  current in the inductor, they are assuming that the circuit is fully drained of energy. That's what is meant by "the switch is open t<0", the switch was left open before we start analysing the circuit so there's no stored energy.